# How to resolve problem with not recognized data in ggalluvial/ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggalluvial

I would like to create a sankey/alluvial diagram in R. I have longitudal data:

```
id state time
1  s_1   t_1
1  s_2   t_5
1  s_3   t_10
2  s_1   t_1
2  s_3   t_9
3  s_1   t_1
3  s_2   t_4
```

My code:

```
df$id <- as.numeric(df$id)
df$state <- as.factor(df$state)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)



ggplot(df, aes(x = time, stratum = state, alluvium = id, fill = state, label = state)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 3) +
  geom_flow(fill = "darkgrey", color = "black")
```

But I receive an error:

```
Data is not in a recognized alluvial form (see `help('alluvial-data')` for details).
```

I think I do everything step by step following the manual example no. 5:

[image]

But I still can't get the plot. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. I can't reproduce your error. Based on your example data your code works fine.

Comment: Thank you for a check. I can't still figure it out. I'll check for a package conflict and updates